# I can't disable relative numbering from vimrc?

Tags: vim

this is driving me insane, i've tried set nonu and set nornu thousands of times in my .vimrc and nothing changes, deleting the numbers.vim plugin made me no difference, does anyone know why this would be happening to me?

edited:

as @Harish said, i did

verbose set nornu?
and this showed me the path to a session.vim that was created in every single directory where i was working on, all these session.vim files were created by this code i have in my .vimrc, which i use to reopen the last file i was working with as soon as i open vim in that same directory

```
fu! SaveSess()
    execute 'mksession! ' . getcwd() . '/.session.vim'
endfunction

fu! RestoreSess()
if filereadable(getcwd() . '/.session.vim')
    execute 'so ' . getcwd() . '/.session.vim'
    if bufexists(1)
        for l in range(1, bufnr('$'))
            if bufwinnr(l) == -1
                exec 'sbuffer ' . l
            endif
        endfor
    endif
endif
endfunction

autocmd VimLeave * call SaveSess()
autocmd VimEnter * nested call RestoreSess()
```

it seems that these session.vim files were not being updated with the new changes done in vimrc. what has fixed my issue so far was deleting every single session.vim file created in each directory in order for the changes in vimrc to take effect

Comment: Hi Brian, with your session saving and session restoring, remove your relative number session setting from these files and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
verbose set <option>?
```

This will say where an option was last set.

```
verbose set nornu?
```

Comment: :) If you did find what was the cause, please update it here. It'll benefit people having similar problems.